# Finding Firefox child window (alert)

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I'm trying to find a javascript alert window, based on its parent (Firefox in this case).

If I fetch the alert globally and check its owner, I get firefox. Why can't I go the other way around and find the alert as a child of firefox?

```
IntPtr firefoxHwnd = GetFirefoxHwnd(); // this works

WindowHandleInfo whi = new WindowHandleInfo(firefoxHwnd);
List<IntPtr> children = whi.GetAllChildHandles(); // 0 items

IntPtr alertHwnd = Pinvoke.FindWindow("MozillaDialogClass", null);
IntPtr alertOwnerHwnd = Pinvoke.GetWindow(alertHwnd, GW_OWNER);

Debug.WriteLine(firefoxHwnd == alertOwnerHwnd); // true
```

http://blog.ralch.com/2015/04/pinvoke-getting-all-child-handles-of-window/

Comment: Owner is *not* the same thing as parent. The dialog is most likely owned by the Firefox window, but not a child of it (which is reasonable - modal dialogs shouldn't really be children, they should have their own message loop). Firefox doesn't seem to be a "good" Windows application - many multi-platform applications aren't.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, I noticed a difference between parent and owner in Spy++.  However,  `EnumThreadWindows` seems to do the trick in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm creating Firefox in a separate thread, this seems to do the trick:

```
delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn,IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);

public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    List<IntPtr> handles = new List<IntPtr>();
    uint processId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processId);

    foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById((int) processId).Threads)
    {
        EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, (hWnd, lParam) => 
                                    { handles.Add(hWnd); return true; }, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    return handles;
}
```